# Cannot read external .cl file. String is empty. (Ubuntu 22.04, C++, ROS2)

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, opencl, ros2

i am facing am problem using OpenCL for the first time (Version 1.2, on Ubuntu 22.04LTS).
I am trying to work with OpenCL and ROS2 together, so the following code is executed in a ROS2 node through a launch file.
I installed the drivers from Intel SDK and try to execute the kernel on the Intel UHD Graphics.

```
cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);
std::ifstream kernelFile("Smc.cl");
std::string src(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(kernelFile), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
cl::Program::Sources sources (1, std::make_pair(src.c_str(), src.length() + 1));

context = cl::Context(devices[0]);
program = cl::Program(context, sources);
program.build();
```

I am trying to read the kernel from "Smc.cl", which is in the same directory as the .cpp file.

The kernel looks like this (is just a dummy kernel for tests at the moment):

```
__kernel void dummy(__global int* a, __global int* b) 
{
    int gid = get_global_id[0];

    b[gid] = a[gid];
}
```

However, the "src" string is empty and when i do:

`cl_int num = program.getInfo<CL_PROGRAM_NUM_KERNELS>();`

and print "num", it's value is zero.

Can anybody help me here?

The program build works fine and everything else too.
There are no error codes regarding the just in time compilation.
Also my platforms and devices are recognized by the OpenCL drivers.

Comment: Always check that you open files successfully before trying to use them. Where is this `Smc.cl` file, in relation to your process [*working directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)? I'll guess it's not in the current working directory, but somewhere else and the program can't open it.

Comment: Fixed it! Had to pass the absolute path for some reasons.

Comment: The lesson from this: The working directory (from which all relative paths are relative to) might not be what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a build tool like cmake, you might have to tell the build tool to copy these files into the build directory. Only then they will be added to the executable. For example in cmake add this to the CMakeLists.txt:

```
#add target that copies the file
add_custom_target(copy_cl_file ALL COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Smc.cl
        ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Smc.cl
        COMMENT "Copying cl file")

#add dependency to your executable target
add_dependencies(YOUR_TARGET_NAME copy_cl_file)
```

if you have a bunch if .cl files in a specific directory your can also use the `copy_directory` command